# How to combine multiple complex queries?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

There is a query that displays data by id (R_PERS_ACCOUNT_ID) and date (MAX(RBS.CREATE_DATE))

```
Select rpao.r_pers_account_id, max(rbs.create_date)
from r_base_trans rbs
         join r_pers_acc_operation rpao on rbs.r_base_trans_id = rpao.r_base_trans_id
where rbs.create_date between to_date('01.12.2017', 'dd.mm.yyyy') and to_date('31.12.2020', 'dd.mm.yyyy')
  and rbs.M_BASE_TRANS_TYPE_ID NOT IN 26
  and ROWNUM < 100
group by rpao.r_pers_account_id;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z09td.png)

There is one more request in which you need to insert data from the previous select. In the where clause where pa.r_pers_account_id, you need to insert the id from the previous table. And in to_date('31-01-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy') there is also date data from the previous table. (In my case, I manually inserted only one data)

```
select TP.IIN_BIN,
       pa.r_pers_account_id,
       pa.close_date,
       kbk.kbk_code,
       org.code_nk,
       org.CODE_TPK,
       op.m_operation_type_id,
       pa.open_date,
       sum(op.amount)
from r_pers_account pa
         join r_tax_payer tp on pa.r_tax_payer_id = tp.r_tax_payer_id
         join r_pers_acc_operation op on op.r_pers_account_id = pa.r_pers_account_id
         join m_kbk kbk on kbk.m_kbk_id = pa.m_kbk_id
         join m_tax_org org on org.m_tax_org_id = pa.m_tax_org_id
where pa.r_pers_account_id in (16616864)
  and is_charge_fine = 0
  and trunc(op.actual_date, 'fmdd') <= to_date('31-01-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
  and op.m_operation_type_id = 1
group by tp.IIN_BIN, pa.r_pers_account_id, pa.close_date, kbk.kbk_code, op.m_operation_type_id, org.code_nk,
         org.code_tpk, pa.open_date;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9N0p.jpg)

In this select, you also need to insert data by id and date.

```
select TP.IIN_BIN,
       pa.r_pers_account_id,
       pa.close_date,
       kbk.kbk_code,
       org.code_nk,
       org.CODE_TPK,
       op.m_operation_type_id,
       pa.open_date,
       sum(op.amount)
from r_pers_account pa
         join r_tax_payer tp on pa.r_tax_payer_id = tp.r_tax_payer_id
         join r_pers_acc_operation op on op.r_pers_account_id = pa.r_pers_account_id
         join m_kbk kbk on kbk.m_kbk_id = pa.m_kbk_id
         join m_tax_org org on org.m_tax_org_id = pa.m_tax_org_id
where pa.r_pers_account_id in (16616864)
  and is_charge_fine = 0
  and trunc(op.actual_date, 'fmdd') <= to_date('31-01-2018', 'dd-mm-yyyy')
  and op.m_operation_type_id = 2
group by tp.IIN_BIN, pa.r_pers_account_id, pa.close_date, kbk.kbk_code, op.m_operation_type_id, org.code_nk,
         org.code_tpk, pa.open_date;
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jy0Qv.jpg)

**It is necessary to make so that these 3 requests were one select.**

In addition, after combining these queries, you need to display data by condition if the second select column sum(op.amount) has a negative number, and the third select column sum(op.amount) has 0 or a positive number

Comment: Tag spam doesn't help us help you; it makes it harder to. Tagging multiple conflicting tags means that we have no idea what technology you are really asking about, making your question unclear and difficult to answer. Tag spam can easily end up attracting downvotes and also close votes if they make the question unclear. Just tag the technologies you are actually asking about. I've gone ahead and removed all the tags and added the generic [[tag:sql]] tag; [edit] your question to tag appropriately, please.

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what queries you posted do (2nd and 3rd look just the same to me), but - generally speaking - if you want to "reuse" one query in queries that follow, there's a useful option: **CTE** (common table expression, i.e. the `WITH` factoring clause).

Simplified, it would look like this; I hope you'll manage to apply it to your code:

```
with
first_query as
  (select rpao.r_pers_account_id, ...
   from ...
   where ...
  ),
second_query as
  (select tp.iin_bin, ...
   from FIRST_QUERY f1 join r_per_account pa on ...
        --------------
        -- this is new!
        join ...
   where ...
  ),
third_query as
  (select tp.iin_bin, ...
   from ...
      -- use SECOND_QUERY (and/or FIRST_QUERY, if you have to)
   where ...
  )
-- Finally: extract data you really need
select ...
from third_query t3
where ...
```

Comment: sorry, in the second query op.m_operation_type_id equals to 1 and in the third query op.m_operation_type_id equasl to 2

Comment: do you know how to do this task ---> In addition, after combining these queries, you need to display data by condition if the second select column sum(op.amount) has a negative number, and the third select column sum(op.amount) has 0 or a positive number